# AWS Lambda NodeJS : Retrieve a value from parameter store and save it into a variable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-parameter-store

I am trying to create a nodeJs app that gets an encrypted string from the AWS parameter store and uses it as a password for basic access authentication (username and password based authentication). For some reason though (probably asynchronous behaviour of nodeJs), I'm unable to assign the values correctly to the global variable as can be seen in the below code and stakc trace :

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ssm = new AWS.SSM({region: 'us-east-1'});
var authPass = 'default';
let authUser = 'user';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Get request and request headers
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;

    getParameterFromSystemManager( 
        (data) => {
            authPass = data;
            console.log('Inside func authPass : ', authPass); //This is where the printed value is 'password2' i.e. actual expected string
        }
    );
    
    console.log("Outside function call : ", authPass);  //This is where the printed value is 'default' when it should be password2

    // Construct the Basic Auth string
    const authString = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(authUser + ':' + authPass).toString('base64');
    
    
    // Require Basic authentication
    if (typeof headers.authorization == 'undefined' || headers.authorization[0].value != authString) {
        const body = 'Unauthorized';
        const response = {
            status: '401',
            statusDescription: 'Unauthorized',
            body: body,
            headers: {
                'www-authenticate': [{key: 'WWW-Authenticate', value:'Basic'}]
            },
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }
    callback(null, request);
};


function getParameterFromSystemManager(callback) {
    var params = {
        Name: '/Path/ToPassword/EncryptedString',
        WithDecryption: true
    };
    ssm.getParameter(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        } else {
            callback(data.Parameter.Value);
        }
    });
}
```

As it can be seen above that the main authentication function has 2 console logs. When I test the lambda function this is the output that I receive  :

```
Function Logs
START RequestId: 7d2eaccf-f064-4a5b-94c2-f8ff666dxxxx Version: $LATEST
2023-05-18T00:21:13.937Z    7d2eaccf-f064-4a5b-94c2-f8ff666dxxxx    INFO    Outside function call :  default
2023-05-18T00:21:14.177Z    7d2eaccf-f064-4a5b-94c2-f8ff666dxxxx    INFO    Inside func : data password2 authPass password2
END RequestId: 7d2eaccf-f064-4a5b-94c2-f8ff666dxxx
REPORT RequestId: 7d2eaccf-f064-4a5b-94c2-f8ff666dxxxx  Duration: 676.17 ms Billed Duration: 677 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 81 MB  Init Duration: 503.74 ms
```

Comment: I'm not a node person, but shouldn't it use `await getParameterFromSystemManager()` to wait for the function to complete?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yeah I thought of that too but getParameterFromSystemManager()  is not explicitly defined as an async function so when I tried to use await getParameterFromSystemManager(), I got a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little digging and found that the following minor changes make the code work. Posting this here just in case somebody else has a similar issue in the future :

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ssm = new AWS.SSM({region: 'us-east-1'});
let authPass;
let authUser = 'user';

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    // Get request and request headers
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;
    authPass = await getParam('/Path/ToPassword/EncryptedString');
    
    console.log("authUser : ", authUser);

    // Construct the Basic Auth string
    const authString = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(authUser + ':' + authPass).toString('base64');
    
    
    // Require Basic authentication
    if (typeof headers.authorization == 'undefined' || headers.authorization[0].value != authString) {
        const body = 'Unauthorized';
        const response = {
            status: '401',
            statusDescription: 'Unauthorized',
            body: body,
            headers: {
                'www-authenticate': [{key: 'WWW-Authenticate', value:'Basic'}]
            },
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }
    callback(null, request);
};


const getParam = param => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    ssm.getParameter({
      Name : param,
        WithDecryption: true
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return rej(err)
        }
        return res(data.Parameter.Value)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you have done here... Your changes should be quickly spotted by others looking for help in a simila problem. Thank you, and read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)